# В чём ошибка формирования leftJoin?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

В чём ошибка формирования `left join` в yii2?

В phpMyAdmin всё ок.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
LEFT JOIN user 
    ON posts.id_user = user.id 
WHERE moderation = 1 
ORDER BY date_post DESC;
```

В yii2 не срабатывает `left join`:

```
 self::find()->leftJoin('user', 'posts.id_user = user.id ')->andWhere(['moderation' => 1])->orderby(['date_post'=>SORT_DESC]);
```

Сама модель. Может как то нужно связать с таблицей user

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "posts".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $id_user
 * @property string $name_post
 * @property string $text_post
 * @property int $count_see_post
 * @property int $date_post
 */
class Content_posts extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
     public static function tableName()
      {
             return 'posts'; // Имя таблицы в БД в которой хранятся записи блога
      }

      public function allPost()
      {

       return self::find()->join('LEFT JOIN', 'user', 'posts.id_user = user.id ')->where(['moderation' => 1])->orderby(['date_post'=>SORT_DESC])->all();

      }



}
```

Comment: ну дак, а что генерит то?

Comment: Проверяю var_dump выводит только значение таблицы posts, user не вижу

Comment: я про генерируемый sql запрос -> https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/857/show-raw-sql-query

Comment: Тогда не понимаю вопроса ) Ошибку не выдаёт )

Comment: посмотрите какой SQL запрос генерирует ваш код, и сравните с тем, который вы выполняете в пхпадмине

Comment: Теран я вас не понимаю, если бы видел наверно бы не спрашивал.

Answer (score 0):

```
self::find()->leftJoin('user', 'posts.id_user = user.id ')->where(['moderation' => 1])->orderby(['date_post'=>SORT_DESC])->all();
```

Comment: Без изменений.(

Comment: Сделайте: `$query = new self::find()->leftJoin('user', 'posts.id_user = user.id ')->where(['moderation' => 1])->orderby(['date_post'=>SORT_DESC]);`
`var_dump($query->createCommand()->sql);`

Comment: Снова не работает %(

Comment: Здесь ничего работать не будет. То, что я написал выше должно вывести исходную строку запроса. Что выводит `var_dump`?

Comment: Всё верно так и было. Её нужно вам прислать?

Comment: Пришлите.......